# Database design for increasingly large amounts of data (30,000+ items, each getting 48 new updates per day)

Tags: database, database-design

I want to show historical (and current) data for the commerce items in a game. The data is readily available, I just want to determine the best way of storing that data for performance.

Basically I want to store:

- sell price
- buy price
- quantity available
- quantity ordered

...48 times per day, per item, with tens of thousands of items.

I have no experience with storing this kind of ever growing data. I was considering having a serialised array for each item (PHP and MySQL) but that seems a horrible solution.

How would you structure this database?

Comment: So that's roughly 1.4 million rows a day, or 43 million rows a month, or 518 million rows a year. Is that right? Are you sure you *really* want that level of detail for a game?

Comment: I know it sounds a bit much. There are multiple sites doing exactly that, with the same data for the same game. I doubt they are all adding that many rows per day, so there's probably a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would also need timestamp and itemnumber as it's a game, use simple integers - divide timestamp by 48 to get day and time, price in cents (don't use floating-point).

To reduce the sheer quantity of data, only record **changes** - the data for any particular item may not change for a week,so why create nearly 350 records when one will do?

Not really sure what the mechanics of your game are (obviously) but will historical data be significant? Could you keep say the last week's worth on a "live" table and move the historical data to a historical table? Perhaps a "current" table containing just exactly the current data and whenever that data changes, move the old data for that item to a history table and create your new "current" record with a "timestamp" of"now".

---

Record tructure for each file

- **item#**
- **datestamp**
- Recnum (Autoinc)
- Sellprice
- buyprice
- qtyavail
- qtyordered

Primary key in **bold**
Secondary key : recnum,item# (perhaps)

Recnum is autoinc on the current table, integer on history.

When a new record is added to the current table, it acquires a recnum of (nextnum) and datestamp of (now) and the current record for item# moves to the history table precisely as-is. In that way, you can control the loading of the history table(s) held on client machines if you store the highest recnum - all changes **since** that have higher recnums. By adding item#s-of-interest into the key you can restrict the amount of data required to be transferred - if only ten items are of interest to any particular player (or a hundred, or a thousand) then you don't need to transfer the data for the remainder to them - until they take an interest in a new item, when you can transfer the data for that item alone using the indices judicously.

Comment: Thanks Magoo. It would indeed be possible to have a historical table. What kind of structure would you recommend for the historical table? The goal will be to display the data in charts.